# how can I create an android app that updates itself via a crontab set up in the app

Tags: android

I have read many of the crontab android questions here, but have not found an answer.
I have an app that you enter some values into an sqlite database... then I need a crontab type thing running in the app that will execute based on your config settings you set to run every minute, hour, day, week or month which ever you select... and it will read the data from the sqlite database and then using an API interact with my website to do some things.

How do I build this all in the app?
The app can be closed and it still needs this cron job to run.
The only time it would not run is if the device was turned off.
It will auto start on start up or reboot.

Thanks for any directions
Dean-O

Comment: The closest thing to what you seek is `WorkManager`.

Comment: WorkManager doesn't run at a given time, it will run close to that time.

Comment: Correct. It is still the closest thing to what you seek.

Comment: There is nothing that will fire when the time is set to fire?  How far after the time set to fire will WorkManager fire?

Comment: "There is nothing that will fire when the time is set to fire?" -- `AlarmManager` has some stuff that offers that. However, they still will not fire at your designated times, due to Doze mode, app standby, and manufacturer-specific battery-optimization techniques. Even when they do fire, you might not have Internet access, for the same reasons. `AlarmManager` also does not handle your "auto start on start up or reboot" requirement. "How far after the time set to fire will WorkManager fire?" -- there is no "time set to fire". You specify a period with `PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder`.

Comment: So I am trying to make a bot of sorts in my app so that based on the users input it will access my site for data and updates at a given interval they select.  Is that what WorkManager will do for me, or is there something else I should look at?

Comment: `WorkManager` is as close as you are going to get. You are using `crontab` as a mental model, which is unwise. `cron` is used on desktops and servers, and usually those things are plugged into sources of power. Phones and tablets usually are *not* plugged into sources of power, and so battery life is a significant issue. Android developers used to do things like you're trying, without any regard for battery life. As a result, Google and device manufacturers have had to greatly limit our ability to do background periodic work, to better satisfy users' wishes for better battery life.

Comment: So, rather than coming up with unrealistic expectations and designing your app around those, I recommend that you spend some time learning about Doze mode, how power management works on Android, and how `WorkManager` works. Then, design your app around blending your original objectives with battery concerns and Android's restrictions in support of better battery life.

Comment: WorkManager appears to be the process.  Is it possible to build a screen for the end user to configure how often it runs?

Comment: "Is it possible to build a screen for the end user to configure how often it runs?" -- sure. It is probably close to what you had in mind. Just bear in mind that the minimum period for `WorkManager` is 15 minutes.

Comment: 15 mins would work.  Question, how do bot style apps have a smaller time interval?

Comment: like this new one I have seen on FB for weeks...  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.revenyou.youapp&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: They use a server, most likely. The phone tells the server "do these things at these times", and the server takes over from there. What you're trying to do is tell the server "do this thing right now" and do the timing on the phone. Doing the timing on the server is a better solution in many cases (e.g., it doesn't require the phone to be on the Internet at the time of the event, just at the time of scheduling).

Comment: thanks that makes sense... I will look at using the app to update the server side database and have a cronjob on the server process "dirty" records in the database.